# Android code , Display whole data when mobile in horizontal view

Tags: android

When I rotate mobile in horizontal view then how to get whole data display of that page. As of now, data is cuts off . How to write scrolling code so that after scrolling users can see whole page

Comment: code or (question) didn't happen

Answer (score 0):

Try this code.

```
<ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"></LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>
```